# CachedNetwokImage - Resize image before rendering

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I am making an app that displays a lot of images. I am using [CachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) for this. The problem is that when I display these images the framerate is really bad. I wanted to resize those images before displaying them so that I reduce the jank.

I found out about these properties while looking around, **maxHeightDiskCache** and **memCacheHeight**. Setting **maxHeightDiskCache** achieved what I wanted but it also resized the image in cache storage which I did not want. memCacheHeight seemed to be what I wanted from reading the description. But setting **memCacheHeight** didn't seem to work, the images were displayed with their original resolution.

This is my code:

```dart
CachedNetworkImage(
                memCacheHeight: 400,
                memCacheWidth: 200,
                imageUrl: ctrlr.images[index].url,
                imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) {
                  return ImageChip(
                    imageProvider: imageProvider
                  );
                },
                placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
                    child: Container(
                  height: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 8,
                  width: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 8,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )),
                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
              )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: facing the same issue

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with the imageBuilder. If you don't use an imageBuilder, it works fine. Silly that they haven't fixed this.